# Generic Handler not running in mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've added a generic handler (KeepSessionAlive.ashx) to the root of my mvc 4 project.  The code in the handler is:

```
public class KeepSessionAlive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session["KeepSessionAlive"] = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my application and check while debugging, I don't see the `Session["KeepSessionAlive"]` being set.  I tried adding a break point in the `ProcessRequest` method in the handler, but the break point is never hit as I'm surfing the site.  Do I need to do anything else to get the application to pick up the handler?

We had done something like in a webforms project and I don't recall having to do anything else in there.  Also I've updated my route to include:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
        //other routes skipped
    }
```

I added the `.ashx` in there in case that was the problem, but either way with or without that line the handler does not seem to get invoked.

Comment: You should replace that with an MVC action.

Comment: @SLaks can you explain?  As I would need this executed on every page, any controller.  I thought handler was the way to go.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding HttpHandlers.  You should replace that with an ActionFilter.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `OnActionExecuted` method of the `Controller`.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
     public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
     {
         filterContext.HttpContext.Session["KeepSessionAlive"] = DateTime.Now;
     }
}
```

After this just derive your controller from this `BaseController`. This is a more 'MVC-way'.

Another approach is to create a custom `ActionFilter` and apply it globally, as mentioned by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks):

```
public class KeepSessionAliveAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Session["KeepSessionAlive"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

You need to remember to register it

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new KeepSessionAliveAttribute());
    }
}
```

PS: You handler might not be working because you haven't registered it on your `web.config`